# Host...not allowed error in ODBC connection, while connecting to an online MySQL database

Tags: mysql, odbc, database-connection, dsn

I have downloaded MySQL ODBC Connector 5.1. Now am trying to setup the DSN. But am getting the error:

`Connection Failed : [HY000] [MySQL] [ODBC 5.1 Driver]Host '117.x.x.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`

My server url is server.myweb.com - this name am entering in the TCP/IP Server and Port =3306.

I have also entered the userid and password , which is the one which i enter when i open www.myweb.com/cpanel

Is this a version problem? Should the version of MySQL on my server also be 5.1, i.e. the one of the ODBC?

Please help.

Answer (score 6):

Run MySQL Workbench and Login

Go to Users and Privilegies

Select the User and Change Limit Connectivity to Hosts Matching with %

And Save the changes

Comment: Based on the OQ, this is likely the best answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not a version or ODBC problem. This error says there is no user with specified host name. Read more information in MySQL reference - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-accounts-passwords

Comment: sir, in the User and Password fields, which one of the user and password i have to enter, the cpanel credentials(www.myweb.com/cpanel), or the credentials of the database to which to connect to.

Comment: When you connect to MySQL you should specify host, port, user, password (it is minimal required; some of these may be default). User account has a user and a host name, e.g. 'user1'@'hostname', or 'user2'@'%'; in this case 'user1'@'hostname' can connect only from 'hostname', but 'user2'@'%' can connect from any host. Check that your host is allowed to connect to server.

Comment: In other case, i enter www.myweb.com in TCP/IP Server , in userid and password i enter the ones which i enter for www.myweb.com/cpanel , then it says access denied?

Comment: To get a list of all users, run 'SELECT * FROM mysql.user;'. What is you real host name? There should be an user in the table `mysql`.`user` with specified name and host. If you do not have access to `mysql`.`user`, ask administrator about accounts. Also, try to connect through the mysql client tool (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html), e.g. >mysql --host=your_host --port=your_port --user=user_name --password=your_password.

Comment: Hi Devart, I am having a similar issue but instead of the error giving an incorrect IP address as the host, it is giving me a text name of '[xxxx-pbb.pbb.demon.com'] with 'demon' being our ISP provider. Now in the mysql users we already have a user set up with a host that is equal to same IP address that the our Demon line resolves to, however do I need to duplicate that user and replace the IP address with the text above? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, this issue is not about the version of any component.

When clients (ODBC or otherwise) try to connect to MySQL, the server checks the username and password *and* the originating host identity against its permissions tables.  [This KB article](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/HostXIsNotAllowedToConnectToThisMySQLServer) may help you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

in cpanel under database there is an option "remote MySQL" select the option. It will redirect to "Remote database Access Host" add your IP '117.x.x.x' . After adding you ip to remote MySQL the cpanel check the connection....

Note- if your ip is dynamic remove the old ip and add the new ip to Remote MySQL in you cpanel....